# How do you set data-src for phone vs. desktop for a video

Tags: html, video, media-queries, vimeo

Looking at this code, I cannot figure out how the site decides whether to load the SD or HD version of a video from Vimeo.

```
  

<video
tabindex="-1"
role="presentation"
preload="auto"
data-src='{"phone": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/xxxxxx.sd.mp4?s=e178cfb40802c3a61da43abccebbe1f4d7460d48&profile_id=xxx", "desktop": "https://player.vimeo.com/external/xxxxxx.hd.mp4?s=70bf2b2131b71c32119a5e6f558077814bb1515b&profile_id=xxx"}'
autoplay
muted
loop
playsinline>
</video>
```

Does this code rely on JS or is this defined in CSS via media query? How do you actually confirm this code is serving an SD versus HD video for example on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code which makes use of media queries.

```
    <video preload autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/395038718.hd.mp4?s=a49ee0cfb60c92ecbb053c00de10305783207ab3&profile_id=174" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 568px)">
  </source>
  <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/395038718.sd.mp4?s=ef8b2e5d56817dddead406621420754eb510807f&profile_id=164" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 568px)">
  </source>
  </video>
```